# When does the stack really overflow?

Tags: stack

Is infinite recursion the only case or can it happen for other reasons?
Doesn't the stack size grow as needed same as heap?

Sorry if this question has been asked before, would appreciate links to them if that is the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't speak for all platforms, but as it happens, I've just spent some time working with Windows .exe files (I mean, actually studying the binary format of them - I know in a sense all of us here work with executable files ;) ). I'm betting that most other platforms have similar capabilities, but I'm not immediate familiar with them.

Part of the file format itself includes two values relevant to the current discussion:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER {
    ...
    DWORD   SizeOfStackReserve;
    DWORD   SizeOfStackCommit;
    ...
} IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32, *PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32;
```

From MSDN:

> **SizeOfStackReserve**
>
> The number of bytes to reserve for the
>   stack. Only the memory specified by
>   the SizeOfStackCommit member is
>   committed at load time; the rest is
>   made available one page at a time
>   until this reserve size is reached.
>
> **SizeOfStackCommit**
>
> The number of bytes to commit for the
>   stack.

In other words, the linker specifies a maximum size for the program's stack. If you hit the maximum size, you overflow - no matter how you hit the maximum size. You could write a simple program to do it in one line of code just by allocating a single stack variable (say, an array) that's bigger than the maximum stack size. Or you could do it via infinite (or finite, but very deep) recursion, or just by allocating too many stack variables.

The Microsoft linker sets this value to 1MB by default on X86 platforms (4MB on Itanium systems). This seems small on the face of it, for a modern system. However, more modern versions of Windows interpret these values slightly differently. Instead of completely limiting the stack, it limits the **physical** memory the stack will use. If your stack grows beyond this, virtual memory will get involved, so you should still be good... assuming you have enough virtual memory.

Remember, it **is** possible to run out of memory, even on modern systems with huge amounts of RAM and plenty of virtual memory on disk. You just need to allocate really big amounts of data.

So, long story short: is it *possible* to overflow the stack without infinite recursion? Definitely. Is it likely? Not really, unless you're allocating really huge objects.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thanks. Is this a general concept of how stack is allocated or could different OSes work differently? Especially the ones that are UNIX based?

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I believe on Linux based systems the stack size is set as a system wide setting rather than a per-executable value. Otherwise, however, the process is generally similar.

Comment: On a linux based system the ulimit -a tells you the default thread stack size (8MB) it can be tuned to suite your requirements.

Comment: There are quite a few situations for running out of stack besides huge memory allocations or infinite recursion. Smartphones, tablets and other stuff of that kind may come limited in memory. Also, stack is context-dependent: e.g., in kernel mode on x86 on 32bit Windows it is only 12kb.

Answer (score 5):

The stack overflows when the stack pointer is pushed out of the memory block the operating system has allocated for the stack.  Some operating systems will resize the stack as it grows (IIRC Linux does this) while in others the stack size is fixed at the start of the process or thread (IIRC Windows does this).

Possible reasons for overflowing the stack:

- An unbounded number of stack frames (e.g. from unbounded recursion)
- Attempting to allocate large blocks from the stack
- Buffer overflows for buffers allocated on the stack

There are probably other reasons as well that I can't think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

This question doesn't specify which stack is "the" stack.  So, here are a few answers:

## Call Stack

The call stack gets overflowed whenever the number of calls on the stack overruns the amount of memory it has.  The most common way is infinite recursion, but it's quite possible to have recursion that's excessive but not infinite.  For example, computing [the Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) naively will tax any computer.

## Languages

### Stack-based languages

Some languages, like Postscript and Forth, and some virtual machines, like the Java virtual machine, are stack-based.  In these languages, it may be possible to make expressions so complex that they overflow the stack.

### Context-free languages

Context-free languages are often implemented using a stack.  If the strings for the code of these languages gets too complex, it's possible to overflow the stack.

Answer (score 2):

On a laptop or desktop machine it may be unusual to overflow the stack without infinite (or very deeply nested) recursion when running from the main thread... however, stack overflows are not uncommon for:

- Threaded code in which the thread has been allotted a small, fixed-sized stack.
- Signal handling code in which the signal handling context has a small, fixed-sized stack.
- Code executing on embedded devices, where memory is generally scarce.

As an example, if you register a signal handler using  [sigaction](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sigaction.html), if the signal handler does any complex (i.e. deeply nested operations) it is very easy to get a stack overflow on a number of operating systems, since signal handlers are usually allotted a small, fixed-sized stack. Similarly, if you  spawn a thread with [pthread_create](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_create.html), but you specify a small stacksize with [pthread_attr_setstacksize](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_attr_setstacksize.html), then it is very easy to attain a stack overflow. On very memory-limited devices such wireless sensors, it is an art to avoid stack overflows.

Answer (score 0):

My day job involves a lot of work with LotusScript in Lotus Notes, which has fixed stack limits for various scopes. E.g. most variables in a procedure/function must fit in a 32kB stack, except that the content of class variables is stored on the heap.

If fixed-size variables exceed the stack size, code won't compile.

Run-time stack overflows can occur with recursion. This is easy to achieve in LotusScript as it limits recursion of any single function to a 32kB stack. I gave up on using a recursive QuickSort years ago because of this.

Answer (score -1):

If your program exceeds its alloted stack space without any infinite recursion going on, then you're doing something wrong.

Though it can happen if you leave off some asterisks and try to pass some huge buffers by value.

The memory allocated for the stack does generally grow as needed within reasonable boundaries - I'm not sure what the upper limit is on various systems.

Comment: The memory allocated for the stack does <b>not</b> grow as needed.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. The address space for a thread stack is pre-allocated, and pages are actually committed on-demand.

Comment: Only on Windows. Linux grows the stack as needed.